# ODEs are invariant under the given Lie groups?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, symmetric-groups, symmetry

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^{2}y}{x^{3}+xy+y^2}$ is invariant under $(x,y) \mapsto (\frac{x}{1+\varepsilon y},\frac{y}{1+\varepsilon y})$

I can't make both sides equal when I have a variable depends on two variables
I use $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{D}y}{\mathrm{D}x}$ ($D=$ total derivative), but I can't make both equal!!
How to do that?

I want to mention that this example is arbitrary I can not make any invariant when any variable equal any combination of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: what lie groups are you referring to?

Comment: press on the image

Comment: I did, but I don't see any groups. Are these equations with $x,\bar{x}$ a standard description of  a Lie group? Are these generators of some kind? I am not an expert in the field.

Comment: $(x,y)\mapsto (\frac{x}{1+\varepsilon y},\frac{y}{1+\varepsilon y})$

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a transformation group on $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. an application $(x,y)\to(\bar{x},\bar{y})$. Also assume that $x,y$ are related by an ODE:
$$\dfrac{d y}{d x} =f(x,y)$$

Now, the application of the chain rule yields:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{D \bar{x}}{Dx}&=\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d x} =
\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial \bar{x}}{\partial y} \,f(x,y) \\
\frac{D \bar{y}}{Dx}&=\frac{\partial \bar{y}}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial \bar{y}}{\partial y} \frac{d y}{d x} =
\frac{\partial \bar{y}}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial \bar{y}}{\partial y} \,f(x,y)
\end{align}
$$
Again by the chain rule, you can consider how the group acts on the ODE:
$$\dfrac{d \bar y}{d \bar x} =\frac{\dfrac{D \bar{y}}{Dx}}{\dfrac{D \bar{x}}{Dx}}$$
and then check if 
$$\dfrac{d \bar y}{d \bar x}=f(\bar x,\bar y)$$

In your example, straightforward (but tedious) calculation shows:
$$
\dfrac{d \bar y}{d \bar x}=\frac{x^2 y}{x y (\epsilon y+1)+y^2 (\epsilon y+1)+x^3}
$$
whereas
$$
f(\bar x,\bar y)=f\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon y+1},\frac{y}{\epsilon y+1}\right)=\frac{x^2 y}{x y (\epsilon y+1)+y^2 (\epsilon y+1)+x^3}
$$
so the ODE is invariant under the group action.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching to make it some constant time $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and the same for the other side.

Anyway I got it now :)